# Privoxy, Tor and cURL using Zend HTTP

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii

I am really stuck in this, and need expert help. Let me explain what I am trying achieve and the setup. I  had a script which posts over a https form using Zend_Http_Client. On the server setup I have tor & privoxy running. Everything just worked fine, but now I need to make the code more scalable by running  multiple instances of tor & privoxy on the same server.

Hence I shifted the Adapter for Zend from **Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl** to **Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Proxy** . But after changing the adapter I have bumped into a strange error which says - **400 Invalid header received from client** and when I dump the object of Zend client, I see the following -

```
MyWebClientResponse::__set_state(array(
   'json' => NULL,
   'version' => '1.1',
   'code' => 400,
   'message' => 'Invalid header received from client',
   'headers' => 
  array (
    'Proxy-agent' => 'Privoxy 3.0.19',
    'Content-type' => 'text/plain',
    'Connection' => 'close',
  ),
   'body' => 'Invalid header received from client.
',
))
```

I do not understand what is that I am doing wrong. The code is done in Yii Framework so it is hard to share all the classes and Models, but I am sharing the main parts of the code, which are responsible for this -

```
$client = MyWebClient::factory();
$adapter = $client->getAdapter();
$adapter->setConfig(array('timeout' => 120,
'proxy_host' => 'localhost',
'proxy_port' => 8124
));
$client->setAdapter($adapter);
$client->setCookieJar(true);
$client->setParameterPost(array(
'name' => 'firstname',
'password' => 'password,
'login' => 'home'
));
$response = $client->setUri('https://www.domain.com/post.php')->requestApi('POST', false);
```

Here's the constructor of the class MyWebClient, just in case it it required, all other methods are standard.

```
  static public function factory($new = false)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$client))
        {
            self::$client = new MyWebClient();
            self::$client->setConfig(array(
                'adapter' => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Proxy',
//              'proxy_host' => 'localhost',
//              'proxy_port' => 8118,
                'persistent' => false,
                'timeout' => 120
            ));
        }
        return self::$client;
    }
```

The headers are being set in the requestAPI method and the snippet is -

```
 $headers = array(
            'X-PHX' => 'true',
            'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Referer' => 'https://domain.com/index.html',
            'User-Agent' => self::getRandomUserAgent()
        );
        $this->setHeaders($headers);
```

I would really appreciate help in this regard. Think it's privoxy which is not letting go the request out of the server.

Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may need to wrap the user-agent with quotes. Try this when setting the headers and see if that fixes the problem.

```
$headers = array(
        'X-PHX' => 'true',
        'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Referer' => 'https://domain.com/index.html',
        'User-Agent' => "'".self::getRandomUserAgent()."'"
    );
    $this->setHeaders($headers);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but seems like Zend library is doing so already. Cause when I quoted the string the headers dump showed string like '\'Mozilla/5.0 ... \'' . Not sure what's missing :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to use the native cURL library and the cookieJar which comes with it. It worked like expected.

Cheers,
Sachin